# App Store asking for other Apple ID when updating apps

Tags: ios, applications, ios-appstore, apple-id, software-update

My friend's mate reset his phone to prove him wrong about a situation and ever since then when he tries to update his apps it asks for his mom's iCloud password yet it says at the bottom of the App Store, iTunes and iCloud that it's signed into his account.

We have tried backing it up into his computer but that didn't help. What can be done?

Answer (score 59):

If it's asking for a different Apple ID to update an app or apps, then they have been purchased on the other Apple account.

You can't change the Apple ID that an app has been purchased with. Instead, delete the app from the device and purchase it again with the Apple ID that you want the app registered to.